# Rails mailer append_view_path not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm trying to use `append_view_path` in order to render a partial containing some extra information I want at the end of every email sent.

My mailer class looks like this:

```
class PasswordMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => CaseCenter::Config::Reader.get('email_from')

  append_view_path Rails.root.join('app','views','password_mailer')

  def password_changed(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => t('mailer.email_topic_password_changed'))
  end
end
```

When this is run, it isn't adding my partial to the end of the email. (An email is sent though).
My partial is located in `app/views/password_mailer/password_changed_template.html.erb` and just contains a simple HTML element.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You have an unmatched parens. Change the last line to `mail(to: user.email, subject: t('mailer.email_topic_password_changed'))`

Comment: @max Thanks for pointing that out. It was a typo when I was typing out the question I'm afraid! I have edited it now.

Comment: `app/views/password_mailer/_password_changed_template.html.erb` should be like this. You have prepend `_` for partials

Comment: That explains why you didn't get a syntax error. This mailer should be rendering `app/views/password_mailer/password_changed.html.erb` (the call to append_view_path is superflouos) can you add that view to the to question?

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan Thanks for the suggestion, but chaning line 4 to ```append_view_path "app/views/password_mailer/_password_changed_template.html.erb" ``` did not change anything.

Comment: @max when you say superfluous, you allude to meaning that append_view_path is not the correct  of rendering a secondary view for the mailer?

Comment: Thats correct. If you want to render something else then the default view you need to pass the `template_name` option. If you want the mailer to find the view in another path use `template_path`. This is is explained [in the guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-views). Its somewhat unclear here what you're actually trying to do and why you expect a partial to rendered at all.

Comment: @max The reason I want to render a partial is to add a message onto the bottom of all outgoing emails containing information where the email is being sent from.
Do you know if it is possible to mail the ```password_changed.html.erb``` along with a secondary view containing this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood what you are trying to do correctly you can do this with a layout. Which works very much like the layouts used when doing MVC with ActionController.

```
# app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

```
class PasswordMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: CaseCenter::Config::Reader.get('email_from')
  def password_changed(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: user.email, subject: t('mailer.email_topic_password_changed'))
  end
end
```

app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  # ...
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
  <hr>
  <footer>
    This spam was sent to you by EvilCorp. If you where looking to unsubscribe you are out of luck.
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

app/views/layouts/mailer.txt.erb:

```
<%= yield %>

-------------------------------------
This spam was sent to you by EvilCorp. 
If you where looking to unsubscribe you are out of luck.
```

Of course you can also seperate the footer out into partial and render it just like you would in a normal view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  # ...
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
  <%= render 'shared/mailer_footer' %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. 
Thank you!